# Rejection sampling not giving the correct distribution

Tags: distributions, python, sampling, rejection-sampling

I'm writing code to perform rejection sampling from a Cauchy distribution.

```
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

dist = scipy.stats.cauchy
global_max = dist.pdf(0)
```

This is straightforward. The default parameters of the Cauchy distribution in `scipy.stats` are `(0, 1)`. In the code below, I generate a million random points, and only accept the points whose y-coordinate lies below the curve, i.e. less than the Cauchy PDF value at the corresponding x-coordinate.

```
num_samples=1000000

sample_y = np.random.uniform(0, global_max, size=num_samples)
sample_x = np.random.uniform(-4, 4, size=num_samples)

X = sample_x[sample_y <= dist.pdf(sample_x)]
params = scipy.stats.cauchy.fit(X)
```

Finally I compare the actual distribution to the estimated one:

```
print('Estimated parameters =', params)

plt.hist(X, bins=50, density=True, alpha=0.3)
plt.plot( x, scipy.stats.cauchy( params[0], params[1] ).pdf(x), color='red' )
plt.plot( x, dist.pdf(x), color='green' );
```

**Output**:

```
Actual parameters    = (0, 1)
Estimated parameters = (-0.0030743926369336217, 0.7362620502669363)
```

[image]

I'm unable to understand why this is happening. The variance is significantly different. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing for parameter estimation, but you can't use sample mean and variance because Cauchy has no population mean or variance. Nice explanation at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) on Parameter Estimation.

Comment: @BruceET: Thanks for the comment! Even ignoring the parameter estimation entirely, it's still apparent just from the histogram that somewhere the sampling went wrong. That's the confusing bit.

Comment: As for the rejection sampling method, I don't think it will work to work just on $(-4,4),$ unless you're trying to find probability $P(-4 < X < 4)$ for $X$ distributed standard Cauchy.

Comment: @BruceET: Following on your comment, I extended the range to $[-40,40]$ and now the estimation is much more accurate. Thank you! You were right

Comment: $(-4,4)$ might do pretty well for standard normal. For standard Cauchy $(-40,40)$ catches about 98.4% of the probability.

Comment: Generating a distribution with support $9-\infty,+\infy)$ from a distribution with bounded support cannot work.